# Cross Account SQS Subcribe using IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-iam

I have a use case where I have two AWS accounts A and B. And I want to subscribe an SQS queue (Q) (owned by account B) to listen to notifications from an SNS topic (N) owned by account A using a role R defined by A (A gave role access to B).

I followed the steps in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cross-acct-access.html but when i try to subscribe queue Q to topic N, I get "not authorized" error. Also, roles are supposed to used for programmatic access but SQS doesn't have an API to subscribe to a topic (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Operations.html).

How do I make this work ?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cross.account.html) section in the SNS documentation

Comment: Do you know if it can be done via CloudFormation? I can via console, but not CF.